# Geometric interpretation of $|z| = |z+\beta|$ where $z,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I just solved a problem where I had to sketch certain sets in the complex plane, and one of the problems caught my interest. Namely, I had to sketch the set of all complex numbers $z$ for which $|z| = |z+1|$, where I got that it was all $z$'s whose real part is $-1/2$, which is not so surprising, since adding 1 just means we get the reflection along the imaginary axis, making the vectors maintain their lengths.

So for a real number $\beta$ as in the question, the answer is not so interesting as if we let $\beta = a + bi$ for some real constants $a,b$. Now I managed to show that this set of complex numbers that fulfill $|z| = |z+\beta|$ are those with imaginary and real parts related as $\Im(z) = \frac{-a}{b} \Re(z) - \frac{a^2+b^2}{2b}$, which just becomes a straight line in the complex plane. I find it interesting to see the factor  $\frac{-a}{b}$ since it suspects me of something that would indicate that there hides something orthogonal in all of this. I can't really though see how this translates itself geometrically, and I'd appreciate if someone could maybe present that for me?

Thanks.

Comment: On the complex plane, It will be the bisector of the segment $0+ 0 \cdot i$ and $-\beta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the complex plane $|a- b|$ is equal to the distance between the points $a$ and $b$.

So, the locus of points $|z| =|z - 0| = |z - (-\beta)|$ is basically the locus of all points equidistant from the points $0$ and $-\beta$ which is geometrically the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joint the two point $0$ and $-\beta$.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Interpret $|z - z_{0}|$ as a distance.